# User table encryption using aws kms in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have to encrypt user table data using aws kms encryption, i have refreed following code that doesnt work for me, throwing error 'The security token included in the request is invalid.
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://kms.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:'  can someone help me out?

my code is

```
<?php



use Aws\Kms\KmsClient;



// Somewhere in the controller or model

$this->load->config('aws');



// Not needed for EC2 instance role based authorization - for my local instance only

$key = $this->config->item('aws_s3_access_key');

$secret = $this->config->item('aws_s3_secret_key');



$orig = 'encrypt me please...';

$cryptic = 'CiD/AT9S0xQbpFXHDdw7Mq42htuEVj0vwvZzfR+9GRZCahKbAQEBAgB4/wE/UtMUG6RVxw3cOzKuNobbhFY9L8L2c30fvRkWQmoAAAByMHAGCSqGSIb3DQEHBqBjMGECAQAwXAYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMB4GCWCGSAFlAwQBLjARBAxvNDVWPh6W4STdWakCARCAL/nzjIDZ8uQWAMWI1VBoNPt+TCe9qZMMbY1d1PnVjlJGa/BcVdAyN9KruzEOcFl6';



// Testing the encrypt and decrypt cycle

$kms = KmsClient::factory([

    'credentials' => [

        'key'    => $key,

        'secret' => $secret,

    ],

    'region' => 'us-east-1',

]);



// Encrypt - should match $cryptic

$result = $kms->encrypt([

    'KeyId' => 'alias/argus-db-crypt-local',

    'Plaintext' => $orig,

]);



var_dump(base64_encode($result->get('CiphertextBlob')));



// Decrypt - should match $orig

$result = $kms->decrypt([

    'CiphertextBlob' => base64_decode($cryptic),

]);



var_dump($result->get('Plaintext'));
```

Comment: you must be using an incorrect ACCESS/SECRET key pair. Please check your credentials

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an incorrect ACCESS/SECRET key pair.

Try to go to the security credentials on your account page: Click on your name in the top right corner -> My security credentials

Then generate access keys over there and use those access keys in your `.env` file